# make C++ treat unsigned char* as char*

Tags: c++

I inherit c++ source files with lots of calls to `x.append(p, len)`, where x is of string type.  However, in many cases, p is of type "unsigned char *" it caused lots of errors on my g++ (ver 4.8.4).  If I manually change the `p` to `(char*)p`, it will work. But there are too many such instances (poor me!).

Wonder if there is a way to tell g++ just treat `unsigned char*` as `char *`.

Thanks.

**UPDATE 1**

The following code snippet will give an error when compiling with command line `g++ -std=c++11 -fpermissive te1.cc`.   However, it actually compiles (fine but with a warning) when the type of variable `len` is changed from `int` to `size_t`. Unfortunately I can't change the type of the parameter, wonder if there is a way to tell compiler to just treat the second parameter as `size_t` when searching for a version of `append()` method.

```
//content of te1.cc
#include <iostream>

typedef unsigned char uchar;
using namespace std;
string x = "hi ";

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    uchar *p = (uchar *)"tom";
    int len = 3;
    x.append(p, (size_t)len);
    cout << x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Redefining `unsigned` may help, but it's a really bad solution. Just in case.

Comment: I'd try to mechanically replace `unsigned char` with `char` in the sources.

Comment: Replacing `unsigned char` with `char` may change semantics of the code, e.g. when there are some casts:
`
int main() {

    char a = (char)0b11111111;

    unsigned char * c1 = (unsigned char *)&a;
    char * c2          = &a;

    int i1 = *c1;
    int i2 = *c2;

    cout << i1 << " " << i2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
`

Comment: @n-m, unfortunately manual change is too tedious.  Thanks.

Comment: @Ged, all I need is to have overloaded method append() in string class that takes `unsigned char *`.

Comment: can you add an overload of x.append that accepts unsigned char *?

Comment: Consider switching to `char*` if you are actually working with character data, or switching to a different container if you are actually working with `unsigned char` data. Another possibility is to look into making a character traits class for `unsigned char` and then using `std::basic_string<unsigned char, YourCharTraitsClass>`.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

Extending c++ `string` class probably isn't a good idea ([see that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542030/extending-c-string-member-functions)).

I don't know in what contexts in your code the `append` method is used, but You may try to add type casts using your favorite editor and a simple regular expression:

Find pattern:

```
append\(([^,\)]+),([^\)]*)\);
```

Replace pattern:

```
append((char *)($1),$2);
```

See the [small example](http://regexr.com/3c59s) I made.

Comment: "command line option ‘-Wno-pointer-sign’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++"

Comment: You're right, I've missed that. Thank You for your comment, looks like I'll have to find another solution...

Comment: Thanks guys for searching. Wish there is a magic option in G++ to do this (very useful in some cases).

Comment: @Ged, thanks for the regexp, the parameters of calls to append() are function calls themselves with multiple parameters (so there will be "," within it).  So regular expression is kind of tough.

Answer (score 0):

Good grief! *Don't* hack stuff like that!

If you really *must* change the default signedness of `char`, use the proper GCC command-line option:

- `-funsigned-char`
- `-fsigned-char`

However, it would be better to simply fix the code to use the proper type at declaration, and deal with the (few) odd spots where something breaks.

Comment: Unfortunately they are for gcc (c code) not c++ code. Thx anyway.

Comment: What? These switches are for the compiler, both C and C++ code.

Comment: This is where the difference between C and C++ shows up. C use function name to identify the actual function to link against,   C++ will use both function name and parameter type.  I am just hope there is a switch to tell C++ compiler that it can't find matching function, just treat uchar* as char* when searching for that function.